# Price slider not working on Mobile, not able to slide the bars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

i am using below jquery slider which works perfectly on desktop but not on mobile.

http://www.lugolabs.com/flat-slider

library used is jquery and jqueryUI
 codepen url is:  http://codepen.io/rajMrPerfect/pen/qRQLoW?editors=0110

```
.flat-slider.ui-corner-all,
.flat-slider .ui-corner-all {
 border-radius: 0;
 }

 .flat-slider.ui-slider {
   border: 0;
   background: #171616;
   border-radius: 7px;
   }

  .flat-slider.ui-slider-horizontal {
  height: 2px; 
  }

  .flat-slider.ui-slider-vertical {
  height: 15em;
  width: 2px;
   }

  .flat-slider .ui-slider-handle {
   width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
     background: #ebf4e9;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
```

Comment: You need to get more specific

Comment: see the above exam in url  ,, below is codepen url

Comment: http://codepen.io/rajMrPerfect/pen/qRQLoW?editors=0110

Comment: most Q&A websites require you to ask a question in order to receive answers. You did not ask any question. Instead, you made a statement. We agree with your statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine on both desktop and mobile !

Comment: i made it using some other lib

Comment: its there in the codepen link, thats the new lib i have made

Answer (score 0):

using angular scroller its there in above codepen link solved.